# Is HP p212 raid controller supported on Ubuntu 8.04 server LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, ubuntu-8.04, hp-smart-array

sorry for my simple question, however I can't find any useful resources on the internet. Except the official HP page about my p212 [here](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/arraycontrollers/smartarrayp212/index.html). From this I understand that HP doesn't support Ubuntu 8.04. But there could be built-in support in Ubuntu kernel itself. But I don't know where to look for this support list ? Can anybody help me answer my question - is p212 controller supported in Ubuntu 8.04 ?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Two totally different answers ?

Comment: No, I said that if it's not available (as I didn't know), you can make it available yourself with the help of the link I gave. @eewhite has the positive knowledge that it works out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Smart Array card will be discovered and recognized by the in-kernel cciss or hpsa driver.

Comment: How do you know it will be recognized ? It seems that Ubuntu 8.04 runs 2.6.24 kernel and it supports only cciss driver and from page http://cciss.sourceforge.net/ it looks like cciss doesn't support p212 ?

Comment: It's a low-end controller. What will you doing with it? Which server model are you using the controller with? If you're using it for tape, I'd suggest another controller. There are some additional steps needed to get it working with a tape drive.

Comment: My HW is HP DL320 G6 which will run VMWare server 2.0 on top of Ubuntu 8.04 LTS. Just 2 disks in RAID5. No tape.

Comment: Okay. If you can avoid it, I would not recommend using such an old variant of Ubuntu for this. In addition, VMWare Server 2.0 has been end-of-life since mid-2011. It won't install well and is not supported anymore. Also, you can't configure RAID5 with two disks. Have you considered VMWare ESXi?

Comment: Oops, my bad, I meant RAID1, I don't know why I wrote RAID5 :-) I have no other choice than using this strange combination. I need Ubuntu 8.04 to run VMware server 2.0 with no need for compiling drivers (as I had to do so now with Ubuntu 11 - but it keeps frozing server few times in a month). I can't run ESXi because I have p212 with zero memory and ESXi has extremely poor performance with p212 with no cache and no backup battery. Battery and cache is a lot of money my client doesn't want to spend...

Comment: ESXi on a zero-memory controller will still run better than VMWare Server 2.0. Plus it is supported. Do the right thing and try to get a controller with cache rather than a solution that is already deprecated.

Comment: Well, I already run Ubuntu 11 as host of VMWare Server 2.0 and it runs very good - IO performance 10 times better than ESXi which I've tried in first place. However, the problem and the reason is why I want to change to Ubuntu 8.04 is that it now keeps freezing every once in a while. HP had replaced motherboard twice, replaced raid controller and now it looks like its OS/software fault.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not supported by the default kernel on Ubuntu, have a look to the [CCISS driver project](http://cciss.sourceforge.net/).